# Reference request: prolongation via convex (Fenchel) conjugation

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be Hausdorff locally convex topological vector spaces and $\iota: X \to Y$ continuous, injective with dense image and equip their duals $X'$ and $Y'$ with the weak-$\ast$ topologies.
Given any function $f : X \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, there is a canonical way of extending $f$ to $Y$, by defining $\bar{f} : Y \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with $\bar{f} = \left( \left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} \right)^\ast$ where the asterisks denote convex conjugation.

More explicitly, $f^\ast : X' \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and by the injectivity of $\iota^T : Y' \to X'$ we can restrict to $\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} : Y' \to \mathbb{R}$.
Note that if $f$ was proper convex and lower semicontinuous $\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} : Y' \to \mathbb{R}$ is also convex and lower semicontinuous, since $\iota^T$ is continuous.
$\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} : Y' \to \mathbb{R}$ is, however, not necessarily proper.
Finally, $\bar{f}$ is just another convex conjugation away.

In my case I have that $f$ is proper convex and lower semicontinuous as well as $f^\ast \left( 0 \right) = 1$.
Hence, $\bar{f}$ will indeed be another proper convex and lower semicontinuous function.

Have such extensions been studied before? I have failed to find anything on the subject.
In particular, I am looking for a way to calculate such an extension that is simpler than
\begin{equation}
\bar{f} \left( y \right)
=
\sup_{\psi \in Y'} \left \{ \psi \left( y \right) - \sup_{x \in X} \left[ \left( \iota^T \psi \right) \left( x \right) - f \left( x \right) \right] \right \}
=
\sup_{\psi \in Y'} \inf_{x \in X} \left[ \psi \left( y \right) - \left( \iota^T \psi \right) \left( x \right) + f \left( x \right) \right] \, .
\end{equation}

Also, in my case $f^\ast$ is even continuous, so that taking the supremum over $Y'$ or $X'$ makes no difference, i.e. $\left . \bar{f} \right \vert_X = f$ turning $\bar{f}$ into a proper convex and lower semicontinuous extension of $f$.
That classification alone is not enough though, as can be seen from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118467/are-proper-convex-lower-semicontinuous-functions-determined-by-their-values-on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Hahn-Banach, this was not so hard after all.

Note that we always have $\left . \bar{f} \right \vert_X \le f$.
Since, $\bar{f}$ is convex and lower semicontinuous, its epigraph is in particular closed.
Hence, $\left( \iota \times \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}} \right) \left( \mathrm{epi} f \right) \subset \mathrm{epi} \bar{f}$ and $\overline{\left( \iota \times \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}} \right) \left( \mathrm{epi} f \right)} \subseteq \mathrm{epi} \bar{f}$.
Let us denote the unique function $g : Y \to \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ with $\mathrm{epi} \, g = \overline{\left( \iota \times \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}} \right) \left( \mathrm{epi} f \right)}$.
Then, clearly $\bar{f} \le g$.

Suppose there is some $y \in Y$ with $\bar{f} \left( y \right) < g \left( y \right)$.
Then, $\left \{ \left( y, \bar{f} \left( y \right) \right) \right \}$ can be separated from $\mathrm{epi} \, g$ by a continuous functional on $Y \times \mathbb{R}$.
Keeping in mind that $\bar{f} \le g$ there is some $y' \in Y', s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $z \in Y$
\begin{equation}
y' \left( y \right) - \bar{f} \left( y \right) > s > y' \left( z \right) - g \left( z \right)
\end{equation}
By construction, it is also clear that $\left . g \right \vert_X \le f$ such that $-g \left( \iota x \right) \ge -f \left( x \right)$ for all $x \in X$.
Inserted into the above equation, we obtain
\begin{equation}
y' \left( y \right) - \bar{f} \left( y \right) > s > y' \left( \iota x \right) - g \left( \iota x \right) \ge y' \left( \iota x \right) - f \left( x \right)
\end{equation}
Taking the supremum over all $x \in X$, we get
\begin{equation}
\bar{f}^\ast \left( y' \right) \ge y' \left( y \right) - \bar{f} \left( y \right) > s \ge \sup_{x \in X} \left[ \left( \iota^T y' \right) \left( x \right) - f \left( x \right) \right]
=
f^\ast \left( \iota^T y' \right)
\end{equation}
But, by definition $\bar{f} = \left( \left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} \right)^\ast$.
Hence, Fenchel-Moreau tells us that if $\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'}$ is proper
\begin{equation}
\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'} \left( y' \right) > f^\ast \left( \iota^T y' \right)
\end{equation}
which is a contradiction.

Thus, $\bar{f} = g$ and it indeed looks crucial that $\left . f^\ast \right \vert_{Y'}$ is proper.
In this case correct characterisation of $\bar{f}$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{epi} \bar{f} = \overline{\left( \iota \times \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}} \right) \left( \mathrm{epi} f \right)} \, ,
\end{equation}
which may or may not be simple depending on the topologies involved.